# Trigger Tab activate function - JQuery UI Tabs

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

I run into problem.

HTML snippet looks like this

```
<div id="mainTab">
    <ul>
        <li><a href='#tabs-1'>TabGroup1</a></li>
        <li><a href='#tabs-2'>TabGroup2</a></li>            
    </ul>
    <div id='tabs-1'>
        <a onclick="showSubTab1Tab2();">showSubTab1Tab2</a>
        <a onclick="showSubTab2Tab2();>showSubTab2Tab2</a>
    </div>
    <div id='tabs-2'>
        <!-- First Sub Tab -->
        <div id="subTab1">
            <ul>
                <li><a href='#tabs-3'>TabGroup3</a></li>
                <li><a href='#tabs-4'>TabGroup4</a></li>            
            </ul>
            <div id='tabs-3'>

            </div>
            <div id='tabs-4'>

            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Second Sub Tab -->
        <div id="subTab2">
            <ul>
                <li><a href='#tabs-5'>TabGroup5</a></li>
                <li><a href='#tabs-6'>TabGroup6</a></li>            
            </ul>
            <div id='tabs-5'>

            </div>
            <div id='tabs-6'>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And javascript look like this. I am using JQuery UI 1.10.3

```
$("#mainTab").tabs();

$( "#subTab1" ).tabs({
    activate: function( event, ui ) {
        // Update Some Logs
    }
});

$( "#subTab2" ).tabs({
    activate: function( event, ui ) {
        // Update Some Logs
    }
});

function showSubTab1Tab2() {
    $("#mainTab").tabs( "option", "active", 1);
    $( "#subTab1" ).tabs( "option", "active", 1);
}

function showSubTab2Tab2() {
    $("#mainTab").tabs( "option", "active", 1);
    $( "#subTab2" ).tabs( "option", "active", 1);
}
```

If User click on "showSubTab2Tab2". I changed the main tab. Take the user to second tab. and then activate the second tab of subTab2 and If the tab is not previously active This will activate the second tab and fires activate event

Now here is the problem. If user do that twice then on second time the activate event is not fired. I need that event to log/populate some code on frontent.

I can't do that in my function.

Comment: Well its already activated so its not going to fire the event as it doesnt need to. Why do you need it to fire again?

Comment: @PatrickEvans see my edit question. I need to fire the event to log/populate some code as I've multiple tabbed application.

Answer (score -1):

and if you try to check the status previously in `showSubTab1Tab2()`

http://jsfiddle.net/S4nua/1/

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But that does not solve my problem. I need to fire activate event. I've a common method to activate/reload tabs. And I don't know which tab is going to change/activate. That's why I need to fire activate event.

Comment: my method calls the event allways. there's a function called log1. if tab is already active, this method is called. if not, the tab is activated and then the active method is automatically fired.

Answer (score -1):

Try this instead of your "tabs" code. It will fire every time the tab is shown:

```
$('a[href="#subTab2"]').on('shown', function () {
        ---- your code here ----
  });
```

Comment: The only time it won't fire is if the tab is initially active when the page loads.

Comment: There is not such event as shown according to my knowledge. Educate me if there is any?

Comment: Sorry, using Twitter Bootstrap too much. :) jQuery is "show." http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#option-show

Comment: Check this question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2577261/jquery-tabs-help-with-onshow-function